# In Microsoft Academic Knowledge API, what is 'RId' in Entity attributes?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

According to [documentation for Entity attributes](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/academic-knowledge-api/documentation/EntityAttributes), the attribute `RId` is explained as `Reference Id`.  Does it represents another Entity ID of the paper it references?  If so, I find that a searched paper in this system has fewer references than reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `RId` is the ID of the referenced paper. It may happen that some references in the original are not captured. If you find any specific error related to the Microsoft Academic platform, please feel free to report it [here](https://microsoftacademic.uservoice.com/forums/344310-microsoft-academic-forum).

Comment: Error 404: This UserVoice helpdesk and feedback forum is no longer available.